# How to store OpenGL TextureObjects in haskell?

Tags: haskell, opengl, textures, glfw

I am currently trying to write a graphical application in haskell using OpenGL and GLFW-b. I am rather new to OpenGL, and I am having some problems displaying the TextureObjects. I have tried two ways of doing it.

The first way I tried was to store the textures as an TextureObject, and then simply using it as an input argument to the render function (see below). However, this doesn't work, as 
[the texture objects simply appear as white squares.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJTj.png)
I will also note that it probably took several second for the program to start, presumably because it loaded all the graphics.

The second thing I tried was to store the textures as an IO TextureObject. [This worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvh1k.png)
, but it is very slow. It slows down to a few frames per second. I suspect this is because the textures need to be reloaded every time they are drawn. In order to test this, I renamed the textures while the program are running, and indeed the program crashed, confirming that it needs to reload the textures every iteration.

The texture is loaded with the function

```
loadTexture' :: FilePath -> IO TextureObject
loadTexture' f = do
    tex <- either error id <$> readTexture f

    textureFilter Texture2D $= ((Linear', Nothing), Linear')

    return tex
```

and rendered with

```
renderTexture :: Area -> Area -> TextureObject -> IO()
renderTexture window area tex =
    let (x,x') = xRangeToGL window $ getXRange area
        (y,y') = yRangeToGL window $ getYRange area

     in do textureBinding Texture2D $= Just tex
           renderPrimitive Quads $ do
               col
               txc 1 1 >> ver x' y'
               txc 1 0 >> ver x' y
               txc 0 0 >> ver x  y
               txc 0 1 >> ver x  y'
    where col     = color    (Color3 1.0 1.0 1.0 :: Color3    GLfloat)
          ver x y = vertex   (Vertex2 x y        :: Vertex2   GLfloat)
          txc u v = texCoord (TexCoord2 u v      :: TexCoord2 GLfloat)
```

The OpenGL settings are

```
clearColor            $= Color4 r g b 1.0
depthFunc             $= Just Lequal
blendFunc             $= (SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha)
normalize             $= Enabled
texture Texture2D     $= Enabled
shadeModel            $= Smooth
```

This is my first post, so please tell me if I have missed something, and thank you for your kind assistance!

**Bad practice solution:**

I have come up with a solution, I have added it as an edit, rather than a solution, because I'm not certain that it is good practice --- it is not the type of answer I would like to have to this post, but it can still be of use to those who wish to answer.

Calling `loadTexture` using `unsafeCoerce`,

```
unsafePerformIO $ loadTexture "foo/bar.png"
```

works. However, rewriting the `loadTexture'` function as

```
loadTexture' :: FilePath -> IO TextureObject
loadTexture' f = do
    let tex = unsafePerformIO $ either error id <$> readTexture f

    textureFilter Texture2D $= ((Linear', Nothing), Linear')

    return tex
```

does not work.

Comment: Where did you get `readFunction` from, what type is it and how is it defined? Also why the `unsafeCoerce`?

Comment: Uh, I meant `readTexture` in my previous comment.

Comment: I got the readFunction from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540558/haskell-opengl-texture-glfw).

I think I added the `unsafeCoerce` because when compiling for Windows (using wine) it complained that there was two different types of textureobjects. I added `unsafeCoerce`, and have since come up with a better, safer, way of doing it. I forgot to remove `unsafeCoerce`, so thanks for pointing it out. I removed it, but I got the same result.